# Sort array by date, then by time - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have a booking system that uses for bookings an array in this form:

```
array(6) {
[0]=> array(5) {
      ["date"]=> string(10) "08/12/2016"
      ["start"]=> string(5) "15:00"
      ["end"]=> string(5) "16:00"
      ["booked_by"]=> string(5) "mark"
      ["id"]=> string(1) "4"
}
```

I used this function to sort it by date and to get all bookings in an array:

```
    function getBooking($aula) {
    global $client;
    $keys = $client->keys("Calendar:aula$aula:*");
    $booking = array();

    foreach ($keys as $key => $value) {
        $result = $client->hGetAll($value);
        array_push($booking, $result);
    }

    usort($booking, function($a1, $a2) {
        $v1 = strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $a1['data']));
        $v2 = strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $a2['data']));
        return $v1 - $v2; // $v2 - $v1 to reverse direction
    });

    return $booking;
}
```

I need to sort it also by "start" key to show them in a calendar. I tried adding another usort but it doesn't work. If you need more info please write me back
Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does your booking data come from a database? If so, it would be much better for this sort to happen there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Don't Panic says, if you can do the sorting as part of your database request go for that.

Otherwise, if you are stuck with the array as is - you can extract the data from the `date` and `start` strings, put it in the correct order, then use `strcmp()` when you sort. For example,

```
usort($booking, function($a, $b) {
    // extract year, month and day from date
    list($a_month, $a_day, $a_year) = explode('/', $a['date']);
    list($b_month, $b_day, $b_year) = explode('/', $b['date']);
    // compare the correctly ordered strings
    return strcmp($a_year.$a_month.$a_day.$a['start'], $b_year.$b_month.$b_day.$b['start']);
});
```

Some reference if some of the code is unfamiliar
`strcmp()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php
`list()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Comment: There is a slight problem with this. Because the dates are in m/d/Y format rather than a year-first format, comparing them as strings will not work properly if there are dates from different years.

Comment: @Don't Panic Thanks, well spotted! I've updated my answer so the sorting will now work properly.

Comment: @Steve Your code only works with two elements in an array. It doesn't work when there is more than two elements in the array. sevavietl's solution works.

Comment: @Perumal93, both solutions works. Here is [demo of this one](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a541fab6c5471107922ae8c4a41c568276132cdb).

Comment: @sevavietl Look at the output. `09/12/2012` comes before `08/12/2012`. I have tried your code by my own different test cases, it works but Steve's doesn't work. His code works when there is only two elements in the array.

Comment: @Perumal93, if you are talking about my demo, there is only one date of the year 2012.

Comment: My test cases of date were `08/12/2016`, `02/12/2016`, `10/12/2016`, `05/12/2016` and the output of his code was `02/12/2016`, `08/12/2016`, `10/12/2016`, `05/12/2016`. Your's were `02/12/2016`, `05/12/2016`, `08/12/2016`, `10/12/2016`.

Comment: @Perumal93 can you link to a demo of the code not working? I can't break it based on an array structure as in the original question.

Comment: Yeah. Sure. I will link it.

Comment: Here it is.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1c98a5102de0856ad67a1ad117325c80adbcd662

Comment: One of your dates is formatted incorrectly - you have `5/12/2016` where it should be `05/12/2016`. Change that and it all works as it should.

Answer (score 2):

**The @Steve solution is great**. But you can also use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) and [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
array_multisort(
    array_map('strtotime', array_column($booking, 'date')),
    array_column($booking, 'start'),
    $booking
);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c7abd0715f5be0c0859ba922508988afa7c7daf).

While in this particular situation it is not optimal, it can be more suitable when you need, for example, to sort by `date` ascending, but by `start` descending, or otherwise.

Nevertheless, such operations better to be done inside the database.

**EDIT**

As @Don't Panic said in the comments, the sorting by date can be tricky because of format. To compensate for this we can [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) `'date'` column with [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: I see you got caught out by the date formatting too! I like this method though, not seen it before.